# available scopes for richfaces messages

Tags: jsf, richfaces

What i want is to be able to choose the granularity for the messages displayed in my `<rich:messages />` tag, meaning that the source of these messages could be the entire application, the current page or a single element. What are the options that RichFaces provides?

I am aware of the `globalOnly` attribute, which can be set to true or false, but i don't understand what is considered global and what is not.

So, i am looking for the whole list of message scopes .This list of scopes could be , for example : application, session, page, form. I would also appreciate a small example of each

Answer (score 0):

You could read the [reference doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#richmessages).

A message is typically created like this:

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Error!","An error has occurred.");
facesContext.addMessage(id, message);
```

If the id is null the message is global. So you can either use @for to show messages for a specific component, or @globalOnly to show global messages. If you use neither you will show all messages.